# Single address for a web service

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing

I'm new to cloud computing and suddenly I found myself with a very basic question.
Assuming I need to develop a cloud based service which eventually will need to deploy on hundreds of servers in order to be able to handle hundreds of user logins every second.

How can I create such service with a single IP address/DNS name?

Should I assume that I will need a single server to handle all the initial connections and then redirect to other servers - I doubt that a single server can handle so many TCP connections simultaneously?

Do cloud service provides (i.e Amazon), provide this kind of service out of the box or do I need to develop such/use 3rd party solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to consider here:

1. You only need one DNS address. But every DNS address can have multiple IP Addresses, AFAIK the client than randomly chooses one of the recieved IPs. This is the easiest way to have multiple servers.
2. You could use one very lightweight server, which is just dispatching the messages. You could do something similar also with explicit Loadbalancer hardware.
3. Azure and Google Apps engine - when used as PaaS take care of this scaling automatically. This should be also done by other PaaS providers, since you shouldn’t have any control about the machines, and rather only deploy your code online and wait for it to scale out
4. When you use Amazon’s EC 2, you could do it yourself (AFAIK) and Amazon also provides a service for scaling out. I think if you use this service (I never did) than they should take care of it as well. - However I can’t seem to find this tool/product at the moment.